# Variable initialization when program starts/does_not_start a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, initialization

Could you explain the point of difference between variable initialization sequence if a program starts and does not start a thread?

sec. 3.6.2/3 N3797 c++14 working draft:

> **If a program starts a thread** (30.3), the subsequent initialization of
>   a variable is unsequenced with respect to the initialization of a
>   variable defined in a different translation unit. **Otherwise**, the
>   initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect
>   to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation
>   unit.

Please, give an example, explaining that rule, if it possible.

Comment: What about it specifically are you unclear on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unsequenced* means there is no sequence - the variables could be initialised concurrently, on different threads.

*Indeterminately sequenced* means that one is sequenced before the other - the variables are initialised sequentially, on the same thread - but it's not specified which is initialised first.